# Can eclipse automatically rename the unit test class when the class under test is renamed?

Tags: java, eclipse

I often use the refactor -> rename functionality in eclipse and I also have the habit of naming the associated unit test TestedClassNameTest. But when I rename my tested class I must not forget to rename my unitTest. It would be extremely useful to rename my unit test automatically when the tested class is renamed.

I guess it wouldn't be that difficult to create a plugin that does the job but maybe that isn't even necessary?

Comment: I'm surprised no one even asked this before. It is a really useful feature, especially when classes are moved across packages.

Comment: On a semi-related topic, I'd really like to know if this is available in Visual Studio as well. I think I'll actually ask a question about it... :P

Comment: I've thought the same thing before but you get so used to how things are you simply forget that it could be better...

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA personally for my Java development and it has the same problem. The other problem I run into is that I name my test cases "methodName_shouldDoSomething[_whenCondition]". When I wanted to rename the method under test from "methodName()" to "foo()", it does not rename the test case to reflect this. I am currently working on an IntelliJ plugin which would do these extra bits (test class & test case renames). It don't imagine it would be hard to try the same thing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several googling and eclipse searches, it seems such feature is not yet available.

Today there is no notion of "class being unit tested" in Eclipse. What I mean here, is that you can create a Unit test classes testing anything you want: a full package, a single class, a single method, a full plugin ....

To get more accurate, there is "NO relation in Eclipse's model" between your tested class and the associated unit test.

I totally agree with you that it would be nice to such a feature in Eclipse. To go further it would be really cool to be able to generate Unit tests skeletons and thus have these tests classes linked to the tested ones.

May be you can laucnh the discussion on Eclipse Buzilla, maybe in the PDE category.

Manu

Comment: thx, I've reported an enhancement in eclipse's bugzilla
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/post_bug.cgi

Comment: Can you please just provide the link to the bug entry you just opened ? This one is the global one to post new entries.

Comment: Sorry, that's more like it: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=320715 Bug #320715

Comment: Is there an extension point that will get called when a class is moved/renamed? Because, i'd like to put that in our in-house eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a plugin that does the trick http://moreunit.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

eclipse would not figure this out to change:  It only changes the references of the method used in other classes or in the same class.
If you really want to make this functionality work, you could extend eclipse's refactoring API as I did for my project and give it this new functionality.
If you like to have any references on this just ask me ;-)