# Rename Unit Test when renaming class Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, refactoring, naming-conventions

On a related note to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317789/is-it-possible-to-automaticly-rename-the-unit-test-class-when-renaming-the-class), which just came up:

I commonly follow the naming convention `LibraryClass` <-> `LibraryClassTests` for my unit tests. However, when renaming `LibraryClass` using the default rename/refactor functionality in either Visual Studio, R# or CodeRush (I have tested both) the test file is not renamed, meaning I might have class called `LibraryClassTests`that tests the class `ClassWithNewName`.

Is there a way to configure Visual Studio and/or an extension to the same so that whenever I change the name of a file, the corresponding unit test is also changed?

Comment: Write it in the Forum of CodeRush. there is allways someone who writes you that extension.
on the other hand, its not that hard to do. DXCore extensions are fast written.

Comment: Now I have - lets hope someone comes up with something :P

Comment: Did you end up finding something Tomas? I'm looking for this as well :)